# How to get my code to display the numbers entered from least to greatest

Tags: java, integer, numbers

I am having trouble getting the numbers to go in ascending order from least to greatest.

Enter first integer:6
Enter first integer:1
Enter first integer:5

Case (2)
Enter first integer:9
Enter first integer:7
Enter first integer:2

This is my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

  public class AscendingOrder
  {
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       
       System.out.print("Enter first integer: ");
       int number1 = input.nextInt();
       
       System.out.print("Enter second integer: ");
       int number2 = input.nextInt();
       
       System.out.print("Enter third integer: ");
       int number3 = input.nextInt();
       
       System.out.println("Order ascending: " + number1 + ", " + number2 + " ," + number3);
 
       
       int temp;
       if(number2 < number1 || number3 < number1)

       {
       
         if(number2 < number1)
         {
               temp = number1;
               number1 = number2;
               number2 = temp;
          }
          if (number3 < number1)
          {
             temp = number1;
             number1 = number3;
             number3 = temp;
           }
           if (number3 < number2)
           {
                 temp = number2;
                 number2 = number3;
                 number3 = temp; 
            }
                       
          }
       }
    }
```

Comment: Is this homework? Are you allowed to use arrays?

Comment: Move the print statement that displays the ascending order inside the conditional block that checks if sorting is necessary. This way, the numbers will only be displayed in ascending order if they were actually sorted.